# Why conditions are required to only compute half of a integral (due to symmetry)?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(4-y)dydx\\=2\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(4-y)dydx\quad (1)\\=2\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(4-y)dydx\quad (2)$$

(1) is true assuming that $(4-y)$ is even with respect to the y-axis i.e. $(4-y)$ is symmetric about the x-z plane.

(2) is true assuming what conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you want the integral
$$f(x)=\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}(4-y)dy$$
to be an even function. Is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is there any way to do this without computing the inner integral?

Comment: Also, (1) is not true. Just compute both integrals and you will get something different. To get $(1)$, you need that the integrand $f(x,y)$ is an even function with respect to $y$. Namely $f(x,-y)=f(x,y)$.

Comment: No. The bounds on the integral are very important. If you start playing around with the bounds and integrand, you will see why.

Comment: Although, I will say, you don't necessarily have to compute the inner integral, just understand its symmetry as a function of $x$.

Comment: Do you know of any algorithmic technique to understand its symmetry as a function of x without computing the integral?

Comment: What I'm saying is, define $f(x)$ as the above integral. Now a function is even if $f(-x)=f(x)$. Plug in $-x$ on the bounds of the integral. Because of the $x^{2}$ term in the bounds, the $-$ sign goes away and you have $f(-x)=f(x)$. Notice that I never COMPUTED the integral. I just used the integral directly...does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thanks.